# Firebase Cloud Messaging Web - onMessage not firing

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to integrate FCM into my Next.js app. I have a hook to handle the messaging, but it isn't receiving my test messages. The code produces no errors either client side or server side, and logging shows that the `onMessage` callback is set, but after calling the API to send a test message, the client does not execute the callback.

**_app.tsx**

```
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
    initializeFirebase();
    useMessaging();

    return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}
```

**hooks.ts**

```
export function useMessaging() {
    const [user] = useAuthState(getAuth());
    const [token, setToken] = useState<string | null>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        // VAPID_KEY is imported from another file
        getToken(getMessaging(), { vapidKey: VAPID_KEY })
            .then((token) => {
                setToken(token);
                onMessage(getMessaging(), (message) => {
                    // For testing, log that the message was received
                    console.log({ message });
                });
            })
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (user && token) {
            // For testing, log the token
            console.log({ token });
        }
    }, [user, token]);
}
```

**/api/test.ts**

```
export default async function handler(
    req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse
) {
    const serviceAccount = JSON.parse(
        decodeURI((process.env as MoodGraphEnv).FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT)
    ) as ServiceAccount;

    if (getApps().length === 0) {
        initializeApp({
            credential: cert(serviceAccount),
            databaseURL: 'https://my-app-123456-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com',
        });
    }

    const message: Message = {
        notification: {
            title: 'Hello world!',
            body: 'The notification worked!',
        },
        token:
            // During testing I replace this with the token logged to the browser console
            'token_goes_here',
    };

    getMessaging()
        .send(message)
        .then((messagingResponse) => {
            console.log('Successfully sent message:', messagingResponse);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error sending message:', error);
        });

    res.status(200).json({});
}
```

I am not sure why the callback is not executed, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Julian. Can you check this [GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2210#issuecomment-536466335) and see if it is correctly set for you in your case?

Comment: Hi Julian. Any progress on the issue? Were you able to resolve it and did you go through the link I provided to you in the previous comment?